# Resolving external submodule dependences in webpack

Tags: javascript, dependencies, webpack, physicsjs

I am trying to include a modular third-party library ([PhysicsJS](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS)) into my webpack project. This library is AMD- and CommonJS-friendly, and has well-formed submodules that I want to access. However it is primarily structured for RequireJS, via its `packages` definition spec in `require.config()`, so the entry point isn't a standard `index.js`. Instead the entry point is `physicsjs.js`.

In other words, I can't seem to figure out how to configure webpack to resolve both the library's main file and its submodules. It just seems like if the library's entry point isn't `index.js` and it has submodules, you are out of luck, and I just can't believe that's correct, so I must be missing something.

So, how can the following statements be made to resolve?

```
require('physicsjs'); // entry point
require('physicsjs/bodies/rectangle');  // submodule
```

I have tried variations of this config:

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
        'js/bower_components'
    ],
    alias: {
        'physicsjs': 'PhysicsJS/dist/',
        // doesn't find physicsjs.js

        'physicsjs': 'PhysicsJS/dist/physicsjs.js'
        // doesn't find the submodules
    }
},
```

The directory structure looks something like this:

```
+ js
  - main.js
  + bower_modules
    + PhysicsJS
      + dist
        - physicsjs.js // module entry point
        + bodies
          - rectangle.js // desired submodule
  + lib
    - MyModule.js
```

Note that PhysicsJS does have a minified version of the entire library, which I will use if there is no other alternative, but I would rather only load what I actually use.

Also, the submodules themselves use `require('physicsjs')`, so calling `require('physicsjs/physicsjs')` is *not a solution*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to declare the alias twice, first as an exact match (using a trailing `$`) and then again as a normal match (no trailing `$`). So my config now looks more like this:

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
        'js/bower_components'
    ],
    alias: {
        'physicsjs$': 'PhysicsJS/dist/physicsjs.js', // Exact match
        'physicsjs': 'PhysicsJS/dist' // and again with a fuzzy match
    },
},
```